# Persist dropdownlist value on post ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a dropdownlist and a pagination system. I need to keep the selected index value of the dropdownlist when I click on one of pagination links.

This is the dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("typeId", types, "-- Filter by type --", new { style= "width: 110px;", onchange = "location.href='" + Url.Action("List", new { month = selectedMonth, year = selectedYear }) + "?typeId=' + $(this).val()" })
```

And the pagination system:

```
<div style="margin-top: 15px">

    <span>
        @Html.ActionLink("First", "List", new { month = months[0].Item1, year = months[0].Item3 })
    </span>
    <span style="margin-right: 15px">
        @Html.ActionLink("Previous", "List", new { month = previousMonth, year = previousMonthYear })
    </span>
    @foreach (var entry in months)
    {
        if (selectedMonth == entry.Item1 && selectedYear == entry.Item3)
        { 
        <span>
            @Html.ActionLink(entry.Item2, "List", new { month = entry.Item1, year = entry.Item3 }, new { @class = "current" })
        </span>
        }
        else
        {
        <span>
            @Html.ActionLink(entry.Item2, "List", new { month = entry.Item1, year = entry.Item3 })
        </span>
        }
    }
    <span style="margin-left: 15px">
        @Html.ActionLink("Next", "List", new { month = nextMonth, year = nextMonthYear })
    </span>
    <span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Last", "List", new { month = months[11].Item1, year = months[11].Item3 })
    </span>
</div>
```

Any idea appreciated.

PD: I want to pass the selected value as a route value on pagination link click.

I tried to do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Last", "List", new { month = months[11].Item1, year = months[11].Item3, typeId = "$('#typeId option:selected')" })
```

but I get an A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) error. How can I prevent this error ?

Answer (score 0):

If there will be postback dropdown will loose its values as it is MVC we cannot use ViewState. So what I suggest is either:

1. Take this dropdown out of Form tag
2. Let value go in controller and return it back to Viewstate
3. Do Partial rendering of views

Not sure if it will help with respect to your current structure.

Answer (score 0):

A trick might be to use AJAX to load the next page when you switch using the drop down or set the page number in the query string and on page load, get the page number from the query string and set the selected value on the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround (with help form my colleagues): an old fashioned html link, where I set the url like this:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("List", "Notifications", new { month = months[0].Item1, year = months[0].Item3 }) + (typeId.HasValue ? "/" + typeId.Value : ""))">First</a>
```